# DateTimePicker Asp. net. How to link textbox with HiddenField which is run at server

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, smalot-datetimepicker

I use this datetimepicker : https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker. 
I need to get a value which I pick to server side, but I always get empty value.

I tried something like this:

```
<div class="input-group date form_date col-md-2" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="HiddenDate2" data-link-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenDate2" Value="" runat="server" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use onSelect event in your jquery

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


 <div class="form-group DateTime col-lg-3">
  <div class="input-group datetimepicker">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
  </div>
 </div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('.DateTime .input-group.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
onSelect: function(){
    $("#<%=HiddenDate2.ClientID%>").val(this.value)
   }
});
```

Refer: [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SchweizerSchoggi/j2us0kj8/)